# Setting filetype for all open buffers in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a copious amount of files opened in vim.

How can I set filetype to, let's say, fortran for each of them, so I won't have to do the command for every file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working with recognizable fortran files (extension `*.f,*.for,*.fortran,*.fpp,*.ftn,*.f77,*.f90,*.f95,*.f03,*.f08`) Vim should be able to set their filetype by himself. Just put this line in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

But, to answer your question, you should do:

```
:bufdo setlocal filetype=fortran
```

Answer (score 2):

I now realize that I asked prematurely.

Here is how:

```
:bufdo execute "setfiletype fortran"
```

Comment: Simplify: `:bufdo setfiletype fortran`